# order displayed before my labels in D3

Tags: rotation, d3.js, axis-labels

I am new to programming and new to D3, I am learning it using the book "Getting started with D3" and all the examples I can find around the internet.

To start practicing I am trying to create a column chart but am encountering two problems with my x-label:

- The labels displayed below my x-axis are not in line with the columns. To be precise, I have numbers displayed before the labels start being displayed.
- I am wondering how to rotate the labels. When I try the rotate attribute all of the x-axis is being rotated and I would only like to rotate the labels. I have found some questions related to this but haven't completely understood the answers.

My data are formatted this way:

```
{"Low_Income_Household_Internet_access":
 [{"Country":"Chile","Value":9.69},
 {"Country":"New Zealand","Value":47.8},
 {"Country":"Greece","Value":25.39},
 {"Country":"Italy","Value":33.26},
 {"Country":"Israel","Value":40.31},
 {"Country":"Portugal","Value":22.72},
 {"Country":"United Kingdom","Value":56},...
 ],
 "High_Income_Household_Internet_access":
 [{"Country":"Chile","Value":59.78701735},
 {"Country":"New Zealand","Value":78.3},
 {"Country":"Greece","Value":81.14},
 {"Country":"Italy","Value":84.44},
 {"Country":"Israel","Value":86.59},
 {"Country":"Portugal","Value":89.73},
 {"Country":"United Kingdom","Value":90},...
]}
```

and my code is the following:

```
function draw(data) {
"use strict";
var w = 600;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 3;
    var margin=20;

var format = d3.format(",.0f");
var  x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, w-margin], .1),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([h-margin, margin]);
var  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(0),
 yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(-w);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + ",0)");

// Set the scale domain.
x.domain(d3.range(data.Low_Income_Household_Internet_access.length));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.Low_Income_Household_Internet_access,function(d) { return d.Value; }) ]);
var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data.Low_Income_Household_Internet_access)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Country)+ "," + y(d.Value) + " ) "; });
bar.append("rect")
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("height", function(d) { return h-margin- y(d.Value); })
.on("mouseover",function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
    .style("fill","red")
})
.on("mouseout",function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
        .style("fill","grey")
})
  .append("svg:title")
  .text(function(d) { return "" + d.Country + ": " + d.Value + " %"; });
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0, 295)")
.call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);}
```